# How can I assgin multiple role to any laravel route?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-routing

I created one middleware to check user roles("superadmin","admin" and "user").

And its working fine for one say for 'admin', if I use single role role.

```
Route::get('users',['middleware' => 'role:superadmin', function () {
    return view('users_list');
}]);
```

But the problem is to give access to multiple role here. I tried this but not working.

```
Route::get('users',['middleware' => 'role:superadmin,admin', function () {
    return view('users_list');
}]);
```

Although here I am getting role 'superadmin' not admin. But I think its wrong.

Please suggest me to give multiple role for any route.

Also I have gone through https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust but found many open issues https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust/issues. Please suggest me if you have any better idea than start with 'Zizaco'.

Answer (score 5):

You need to seperate the roles with an `|`.

like so:

```
'middleware' => ['role:admin|root']
```

> [Entrust documentation](https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust/blob/master/README.md)

Comment: You beat me to it by a few seconds I'll add its covered in the documentation see https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust#middleware

Comment: Thanks a lot for quick and very helpful reply.

Comment: it worked after i removed space before and after pipe